# Custom Annotation pin interfere with mkmapview's showuserlocation on Iphone

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, mkannotation

Normally if you have showuserlocation enabled, and going to mapview, there will blue point zoom in dynamically to the user's current location. However, if a custom annotation pin is created for different color purpose then the showuserlocation ability will disappear.  The code below newAnnotation is culprit.   How do you have both custom pin and also showuserlocation ability not interfered.

```
 - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
 {

 if ([[annotation title] isEqualToString:@"Destination"])
  {
MKPinAnnotationView *newAnnotation = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"greenpin"];
newAnnotation.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
newAnnotation.animatesDrop = YES;
newAnnotation.canShowCallout = YES;
return newAnnotation;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    // if it's the user location, just return nil.
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

    if ([[annotation title] isEqualToString:@"Destination"])
    {
        MKPinAnnotationView *newAnnotation = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]  initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"greenpin"];
        newAnnotation.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
        newAnnotation.animatesDrop = YES;
        newAnnotation.canShowCallout = YES;
        return newAnnotation;
    }
}
```

Comment: Although both OP's and this code will result in compiler warning "Control may reach end of non-void function" so should add `return nil;` at very end.  Also, should autorelease newAnnotation if not using ARC.